# MessageDrivenBean(EJB3.0) when depoyed on IBM WAS 8.0 gives 'no onMessage() method'

Tags: websphere, ejb-3.1, message-driven-bean

MDB class implements MessageListener (javax.jms.MessageListener) and this ejb is packaged as an ear and deployed on IBM WAS 8.0.

MDB listens on a queue.
Whenever there is message on the queue, the MDB tries to listen on to that queue , immediately gives the below exception.

Exception:

```
[4/27/16 18:09:50:420 CDT] 000000c2 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: MQJCA1003: The message endpoint has no onMessage() method. Deployment failed.
[4/27/16 18:09:50:431 CDT] 000000c2 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: JMSCC0109: A message driven bean threw a runtime exception '
                       Message : java.lang.RuntimeException: no onMessage() method
                         Class : class java.lang.RuntimeException
                         Stack : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.MessageEndpointWrapper.onMessage(MessageEndpointWrapper.java:142)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession$FacadeMessageListener.onMessage(MQSession.java:147)
                               : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.run(JmsSessionImpl.java:2846)
                               : com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.run(MQSession.java:862)
                               : com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.WorkImpl.run(WorkImpl.java:297)
                               : com.ibm.ejs.j2c.work.WorkProxy.run(WorkProxy.java:608)
                               : com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1690)
'.
[4/27/16 18:09:50:431 CDT] 000000c2 SibMessage    W   [:] CWSJY0003W: MQJCA4004: Message delivery to an MDB '{project#className}' failed with exception: 'no onMessage() method'  
[4/27/16 18:09:50:469 CDT] 000000c2 ActivationSpe I   J2CA0524I: The Message Endpoint for ActivationSpec {activationspec JNDI} (com.ibm.mq.connector.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl) and MDB Application {project#className} is deactivated.
```

Class the implements MessageListener

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@MessageDriven(
           name = "MDBClass", 
           activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
                                @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", propertyValue ="jms/queue") 
                            }
           )
public class MDBClass implements MessageListener  {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MDBClass.class);

    TextMessage txtMsg = null;
    String strMsg = null;
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            txtMsg = (TextMessage) message;
            try {
                strMsg = txtMsg.getText();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm missing.